# .NET/WinForms Custom Form Border with Minimize Animation

Tags: c++, winforms, animation, minimize

I know I've seen this asked before, but the answers have been inconclusive or unsatisfactory (from what I could see), so I'd like to pose my situation here. I'm creating a program that has a custom form border (i.e. Form Border Style = None with our own controls around it). The program doesn't have the minimize/close animations, but just snaps, instead.

It is a .NET form (using C++/CLR) - is there something I can do? I've seen other programs do this (for example, Photoshop CS6/CC have the restore animation, but not the minimize one).

Is there a property/style I can apply by overriding the CreateParams? I'm game for "hacky" methods, but changing the form border style in a way that lets the user temporarily see the border isn't a viable option here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how .NET methods could "understand" your graphical logic, so I think you will have to hack through paint methods and stuff. Have fun :D

Comment: I was afraid of that, haha. We've actually changed to a custom opacity-based animation and it's working well. It's a shame this isn't a form style/class property.

Comment: Don't be afraid to post your solution as an answer here if it works well. It could help future newcomers!

Comment: I've actually done just that.

Comment: Eheh, i meant as an actual ANSWER, so it could get upvote from people interested, but hey :p

Comment: AArrh! Alright, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a custom animation and figured I would share the relevant code. The following override of the WndProc catches minimizes/restores (including from clicking/double clicking in the taskbar). Be aware, setting the WindowState WILL NOT trigger this - you have to manually send the SC_MINIMIZE lpa with the WM_SYSCOMMAND to the window (or manually animate it). The entire animation code, timer included is below.

```
//Define a variable so it knows what animation is happening
short fade_mode = 0; //0 is fade in, 1 is minimize, 2 is close
short close_on_close = FALSE; //a variable to tell the close handler to re-animate or not - this allows this->Close(); to trigger the animation but avoids a loop.

//The WndProc
        protected: virtual void WndProc(System::Windows::Forms::Message% msg) override {
            switch (msg.Msg) {
            case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
                switch (msg.WParam.ToInt32()) {
                case SC_MINIMIZE:
                    msg.Result = IntPtr::Zero;
                    fade_mode = 1;                      
                    fadetimer->Start();
                    return;
                    break;                  
                }
                break;                                  
            case WM_ACTIVATE: {                 
                if (HIWORD(msg.WParam.ToInt32()) == 0) { //because non-zero wpa here means the form is minimized
                    this->WindowState = FormWindowState::Normal;                        
                    fade_mode = 0;
                    fadetimer->Start();
                    msg.Result = IntPtr::Zero;
                    return;
                }
            }
            }

            Form::WndProc(msg);

        }


//The button event handlers
private: System::Void btn_close_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    this->Close();
}
private: System::Void btn_minimize_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {      
    SendMessage(HWND(this->Handle.ToPointer()), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, NULL);      
}

//The event animation code itself (set to a tick of 10ms) and the form closing handler:
private: System::Void fadetimer_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    if (this->IsDisposed == true) { //In the event that the form opened/closed quickly and has not stopped properly, clean up to avoid crashes.
        fadetimer->Stop();
        return;
    }
    switch (fade_mode) {        
    case 0: //fading in
        if (this->Opacity < 1)
            this->Opacity += 0.2;
        else {
            fade_mode = -1;
            fadetimer->Stop();
        }
        break;
    case 1: //minimizing
        if (this->Opacity > 0)
            this->Opacity -= 0.2;
        else {
            fade_mode = -1;
            fadetimer->Stop();
            this->WindowState = Windows::Forms::FormWindowState::Minimized;
        }
        break;
    case 2: //closing
        if (this->Opacity > 0)
            this->Opacity -= 0.2;
        else {
            fade_mode = -1;
            fadetimer->Stop();
            close_on_close = TRUE;
            this->Close();
        }
        break;
    }
}
private: System::Void loginform_FormClosing(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::FormClosingEventArgs^  e) {
    if (close_on_close == FALSE) {
        e->Cancel = true;           
        fade_mode = 2;
        fadetimer->Start();
    }
}
```

Be sure to set your form's opacity to 0% by default - it should automatically fade in when it's first created/shown (mine does, I can't remember if I've done something else that makes it so).